# Do there exist resources to learn to mask autistic speech patterns?

Tags: resource-request

There exist resources to help people with autism to understand, for example, prosodic elements they do not understand. However, I cannot find such resources for the sending end of these signals; I want to find resources to learning to suppress things like monotony and other tells.

Comment: Hi Johnny, I would like to let you know that you don't have to do this for others to accept you. There are many organisations out there such as [ASAN](https://autisticadvocacy.org/about-asan/position-statements/) that are willing to help. If you would like to talk with me or someone else in private, please message them in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com).